# getting sum of the most recent group by id

Tags: mysql

I am stuck at getting sum of the most recent value of unique book

this is the table looks like

```
book_id     ordered_at(unix timestamp)                                  value
1           1440630635 - assume this is July 1, 2015 8:00:00                    250
1           1440630635 - assume this is July 15, 2015 8:00:00                     150
1           1440630635 - assume this is July 30, 2015 8:00:00                     100
2           1440630635- assume this is July 5, 2015 8:00:00                       200
2           1440630635- assume this is July 20, 2015 8:00:00                      300
2           1440630635- assume this is July 30, 2015 8:00:00                      200
```

Given a timestamp, I want to get the total value of the most recent order by book

Says, if the given timestamp is **July 31 , 2015 00:00:00**,

the query should return sum value of 300 because July 30 is the most recent for book 1 and 2 and

```
1           1440630635 - assume this is July 30, 2015 8:00:00                     100
2           1440630635- assume this is July 30, 2015 8:00:00                      200
```

If the given timestamp is **July 22, 2015 00:00:00**

the query should return the sum value of 450 because July 15 is the most recent for book 1 and July 20 is the most recent for book 2

```
1           1440630635 - assume this is July 15, 2015 8:00:00                     150
2           1440630635- assume this is July 20, 2015 8:00:00                      300
```

**Edited:** I am only looking for the most recent and lesser than the given date

Comment: Try looking for `ABS()` function. You can play with that function in order to get the proper results

Comment: What have you tried?  this seems like it would be a straight forward aggregate and limit query, provided the timestamps are IDENTICAL... which I doubt they are, you may need do truncate down to the minute...  `SELECT sum(VALUE), ordered_At FROM tableName Group by Ordered_At  order by ordered_At DESC limit 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do aggregation in a sub-query to find out the max date for each book before the said date (of July 22nd or July 31st, or other). Only sum up the records found matching the sub-query

```
-- your table structure may be different. This example serves just as a guide
create table test (
  book_id int,
  ordered_at datetime,
  book_value int
);

insert into test values 
(1, '2015-07-01 08:00:00', 250),
(1, '2015-07-15 08:00:00', 150),
(1, '2015-07-30 08:00:00', 100),
(2, '2015-07-05 08:00:00', 200),
(2, '2015-07-20 08:00:00', 300),
(2, '2015-07-30 08:00:00', 200);

-- Result of this will be 450
select sum(book_value) 
from test a 
inner join 
-- sub-query that gets the latest data for each book
(
    select book_id, max(ordered_at) max_ordered_at 
    from test 
    where ordered_at < '2015-07-22 00:00:00'
    group by book_id
) b 
    on a.book_id = b.book_id and a.ordered_at = b.max_ordered_at;
```

If date is changed to '2015-07-31 00:00:00', your result should be 300.

If the desire is to find totals closest to a given date, you could use this query:

```
-- Result: 450
select sum(book_value) 
from test a 
inner join 
(
    select book_id
          ,min(abs(unix_timestamp(ordered_at) - unix_timestamp('2015-07-22 00:00:00'))) as latest 
    from test 
    group by book_id
) b 
    on a.book_id = b.book_id 
    and abs(unix_timestamp(a.ordered_at) - unix_timestamp('2015-07-22 00:00:00')) = b.latest;
```

Comment: It seems OP needs nearest to the given date, not only lesser than the given date.

Comment: Good call, @RP-. Improved example added

Comment: your 1st query is the correct answer. I am only looking for the most recent  by a given date, so future dates do not count. The 2nd query takes future date into account which is not my question intention, just to be clear. Thanks so much for your help.